# validator.addMethod for checking before and end whitespaces

Tags: regex

I want to validate a field with white spaces either before a text string or after. It is allowed to have space in the middle string.

Here is my code

```
$.validator.addMethod("trimLookup", function(value, element) { 
    regex = "^[^\s]+(\s+[^\s]+)*$"; 
    regex = new RegExp( regex );
    return this.optional( element ) || regex.test( value );
}, $.validator.format("Cannot contains any spaces at beginning or end"));
```

I test the regex in https://regex101.com/ it works fine. I also test this code with other regex it works. But if enter "     "   or "   abc  " it doesn't work.

Any Suggestion?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: In short, what is not allowed? other thing, you should choose better variable names (in particular the name "regex" that means two different things in your code).

Comment: When you use the RegExp constructor with a string, you need to escape each backslash.

Comment: only spaces, and spaces at beginning and end are not allowed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just have two validators?

```js
$.validator.addMethod("startSpaces", function(value, element) { 
    var expression = "^[^\s]+"; 
    var regex = new RegExp( expression );
    return this.optional( element ) || regex.test( value );
}, $.validator.format("Cannot contain any spaces at beginning"));


$.validator.addMethod("endSpaces", function(value, element) { 
    var expression = "[^\s]+$"; 
    var regex = new RegExp( expression );
    return this.optional( element ) || regex.test( value );
}, $.validator.format("Cannot contain any spaces at end"));
```